# InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to format a date with time too but this throws an error. The way I am sending the request is:

HTML:

```html
<li class="list-item" >
  <strong>Started:</strong> {{implementation.createdDate |  date:'dd LLL. yyyy' }}
</li>
```

TS:

```js
viewPublishHistory(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  let count = 0;
  this.clientDashboardService.getRequestByRequestId(this.implementation.requestId);
  this.clientDashboardStore.select(clientDashboardReducer.isResponseFromRequestIdReceived).subscribe(status => {
    if (status === true) {

      this.clientDashboardStore.select(clientDashboardReducer.getRequestByRequestId).subscribe(result => {

        if (!isNullOrUndefined(result) && result.length > 0 && count === 0) {
          this.implementation = result[0] as Implementation;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.implementation))
          this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
          count = count + 1;
        }

        if (!isNullOrUndefined(this.implementation.createdDate)) {
          {
            this.implementation.createdDate = new Date(this.implementation.createdDate + 'Z').toLocaleString();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the value  getting in  `{{implementation.createdDate}}`.

Comment: createdDate data type is string and the value is the createddate, which is a date coming from db, when I login i see the date but when I go to another window and returning to the landing page then getting the datepipe error . Not sure its get call issue or any configuration made .

Comment: please share the codesandbox link.Without that its difficult to reproduce the issue and debug